Changing a type of param in application.yml
I have spring application and trying to cache data with Redis. For this cache i am trying to set TTL to 10 minutes and for some reason i can not use long type, only format like 'PT10M'.
My application.yml looks like this:
cache:
    service-available-event:
        ttl: PT10M

Config class:
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("cache.service-available-event")
    public CustomCacheConfig serviceAvailableEventCacheConfig() {
        return new CustomCacheConfig();
    }

    public class CustomCacheConfig extends CacheConfig {

        public void setTTL(Duration ttl) {
            super.setTTL(ttl.toMillis());
        }
    }
}

Error:
Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'cache.service-available-event.t-t-l' to long:

    Property: cache.service-available-event.t-t-l
    Value: "PT10M"
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml] - 62:14
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to long (caused by java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "PT10M")

Action:

Update your application's configuration

Is there a way to change format from long to string for application.yml ?

I mean this is as clear as it gets? PT10M can't be converted into long, if you want to use long use a number, for example 10

no, i want to use PT10M for setting ttl

You can't change the type of the property in your application.yml file. The only way you can use a String as a property, is if the program expects a String when it reads the property. In your case, you need to adjust the part where ttl is read as a property to be a String

I just tried it and had no problem having PT10M get converted to Duration by Spring. My guess is you are also using the propery cache.service-available-event.ttl elsewhere, somewhere where it has to get converted to long which doesn't work for obvious reasons

The "problem" is you are overriding setTTL from the CacheConfig which isn't going to work as that takes a long (and the binding will match the getter/setter). If you want this name your property something different and set the TTL with it.

@M.Deinum if there already is a setTTL(long) then it's not overriding but overloading.

True, nonentheless the issue is the same as for binding it will look at the getter/setter pair.

No, you can't change the type in the application.yml.
You can either change the value you provide, so it can be interpreted/parsed into a long, or you can change your code to accept a String when it reads the property you defined.
Spring can auto-assign fields with values from the application.yml file like this:
    @Value("${your.property.key.}")
    private String propertyName;

In this way, you can set the type you want to interpret from the application.yml.
